# Installing gtest with conan

Tags: googletest, googlemock, conan

I am about to change to conan, in the hope that is will simplify installing my package by my users. It was OK, until I started to add gtest to my package.

During install, I receive messages

```
gtest/1.8.1@bincrafters/stable: Package installed 
conanfile.txt imports(): Copied 4 '.a' files: libgmockd.a, libgtestd.a, libgmock_maind.a, libgtest_maind.a
```

However, during build I receive:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmock_maind
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmockd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtestd
```

My CMakeLists.txt file contains

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_GTEST
    Modules
    ${CONAN_LIBS}
)
```

What is missing? Shall I provide some

link_directories(?)

argument?

(In the meantime, after some trials, I succeeded: Not only

```
 link_directories(${CONAN_LIB_DIRS_GTEST})
```

is needed, but also conan's .data must be cleared.)

Comment: Can you post the whole conanfile.txt and CMakeLists.txt? I am having a similar issue with imgui-sfml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What generator are you using?

I have this in my conanfile.txt requires section

```
gtest/[~=1.8]@bincrafters/stable
```

This is what I have for generators in that section

```
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
```

And in the CMakeLists.txt

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_paths.cmake)
find_package(gtest REQUIRED)
add_dependencies(something gtest::gtest)
target_link_libraries(something gtest::gtest)
```

Note that FindGTest is a built in module, but Findgtest.cmake is a file generated by conan in the build directory.

Comment: I did use cCMake

Comment: I think this sentence is not true: "Note that FindGTest is a built in module, but Findgtest.cmake is a file generated by conan in the build directory." I have a `FindGTest.cmake` file in my build directory and I'm using conan.

Answer (score 0):

The Bincrafters package for `gtest` is marked as obsolete, you should use the one in the conan center.
For that, simply add the conan recipe to the `conanfile.txt/py`.
Let's say you use a plain `conanfile.txt`:

```
# conanfile.txt
[requires]
gtest/1.10.0
    
[generators]
cmake
```

Then you can run `conan install`

Then add the conan instructions to your project's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

You may print a message to see the included libraries:
`message("-- Conan libs: ${CONAN_LIBS}")`.
This should include both `gtest` and `gmock`.

Finally, just include the header, and use the framework:

```
 #include "gtest/gtest.h"
    
 TEST(TestName, Foo)
 {
     EXPECT_TRUE(true);
 }
```