# How to use conan to handle ImGui-SFML dependency in a cmake gcc project in Linux?

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, conan, imgui

I want to handle the dependencies of a `C++/cmake/gcc` project in Linux using [conan](https://conan.io/), and build an ImGui C++ demo as shown here: [using imgui by Elias Daler](https://eliasdaler.github.io/using-imgui-with-sfml-pt1/)

I have used conan to handle `Boost` dependencies successfully, but with ImGui-SFML I am having a linking error.

My `conanfile.txt` has the following instructions:

```
[requires]
imgui-sfml/2.1@bincrafters/stable

[imports]
bin, *.so -> ./bin
lib, *.a -> ./lib

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
cmake
```

And I added these lines to my `CMakeLists.txt` to work with conan:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_paths.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake) 

conan_basic_setup()

link_directories(${CONAN_LIB_DIRS}) 
target_link_libraries(my_project ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Then, inside `build/` I run the following command to build the library and install the dependencies:

```
conan install .. --build imgui-sfml
```

So far so good with conan, the `libImGui-SFML.a` is generated (it is also copied to `build/lib` because of the `[imports]`, though I think the copy shouldn't be required since I'm adding the `link_directories()` instruction).

Then, I generate the makefiles

```
cmake ..
```

Finally, when I try to build the project

```
cmake --build ./
```

I get these linking errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lImGui-SFML
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenal
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lFLAC++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lFLAC
```

The libs generated by conan are static:

```
libFLAC.a
libFLAC++.a
libfreetype.a
libImGui-SFML.a
libogg.a
libopenal.a
```

This post looks related, but didn't work for ImGui: [Installing gtest with conan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57136560/4215721)

Is the program looking for shared libraries?

Am I missing some configuration in the `conanfile.txt` or in the `CMakeLists.txt` file?

---

Edit:

```
Conan version 1.25.2
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue and looks like setup is correct. Could you provide your conan settings/version and maybe push your small project to github that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I edited the question to include the conan version (1.25.2), however, I managed to find a solution so I posted it as an answer. Nevertheless, if you're still interested, [here](https://github.com/spjuanjoc/game_project_cpp) you may find my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this reported [issue](https://github.com/conan-community/community/issues/154), this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60424104/4215721) for a similar question, and conan's [basic setup](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake.html#conan-basic-setup) documentation, in this case the `CMakeLists.txt` should include: adding the argument `TARGET` in the setup, and the call to `conan_target_link_libraries` instead of the usual `target_link_libraries`, as follows:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)
conan_target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

So the `conanfile.txt` just needs these instructions:

```
[requires]
imgui-sfml/2.1@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake
```